# What happens with values that are not returned or assigned?

Tags: scala, return-value, side-effects

I've encounter a function:

```
def open(partitionId: Long,version: Long): Boolean = {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
    statement = connection.createStatement
    true
  }
```

The first and the last statements in the function don't do anything. I know what `Class.forName` returns, but the returned value is not used anywhere and there is no assignment. Same thing for `true`. Just a `true` in the middle of the code.

Could you please explain to me this feature of Scala?

Comment: [If there is no return then the last expression is taken to be the return value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560532/5205022)

Comment: @MarioGalic and what about the first statement in the function?

Comment: [A Driver class is loaded, and therefore automatically registered with the DriverManager by calling the method Class.forName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2093100/5205022)

Comment: @MarioGalic OK thanks. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If there is no return then the last expression is taken to be the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560532/5205022).

Pure expressions in statement position would do nothing and be discarded:

```
def foo = {
  val x = 1
  "hello" // discarded
  x       // returned as result of foo
}
```

Regarding side-effect

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44093721/5205022) seems to have been a way of loading the JDBC driver which is now [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using
>   Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers
>   using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Note despite `Class.forName` not being assigned to anything it does not mean it is doing nothing, it is considered a side-effect of `open` mutating the state of the program outside the scope of `open`.