# JDBC driver error and cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I keep getting the error messages when I run my code attempting to connect to a MySQL server

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
```

This is my code. I've made sure to add connector/J to the classpath and still no change.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vehicle", "root", "root"); // For MySQL only

        vehicle focus = new vehicle("Ford", "Focus", 200, 2004, 3000);

        System.out.println(focus.getMake());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what exactly does this do Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039265/what-exactly-does-this-do-class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-newinstance)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, loading the JDBC driver using `Class.forName` is not necessary since JDBC 4.0 which was made available in 2006 (the driver registers its implementation as service provider and will be loaded by the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)).

Just remove this line and it should work. If you need the class name, its a good idea to consult the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html) of Connector/J. Take care to read the docs for the correct driver version because the class name changed (currently it's com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver).

**Update**

As Mark Rotteveel pointed out, `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` will not lead to a ClassNotFoundException when used with newer version of Connector/J. At least the newest driver produces a warning:

> Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new
> driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is
> automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver
> class is generally unnecessary.

Knowing this, removing `Class.forName` won't help since the exception simply means, that the driver is not on the class path.

Comment: Hi when i comment out the line and run the script i get the following error
```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vehicle?autoCorrect=true
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
        at App.main(App.java:7)
```

Comment: Then the driver is not on the class-path or you're using a really old version (I can't imagine this, because even Connector/J 5.1 was JDBC 4.0 compliant). Which versions (Java, Connector/J) are you using?

Comment: Ive got a class path environmental variable pointing to the connector jar

Comment: Don't set the evironment variable CLASS_PATH. Just call `java -cp path/to/connector.jar;. App` if you're in the directory containing the App.class file (otherwise replace the dot with the path to the directory containing App.class). If you're on Linux or Mac use a colon instead of a semicolon as separator.

Comment: is there a way to do that in vscode

Comment: Have a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-classpath-for-unmanaged-folders) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder). You can also open a terminal within VS Code and enter the java command above manually.

Comment: The fact `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` produces a `ClassNotFoundException` means that the driver is not on the classpath, so just removing the `Class.forName` line will not solve any problem, it will just move the problem to `DriverManager.getConnection` (throwing a SQLException with a "No suitable driver found" message).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I've checked this and you're right: the MySQL driver produces a warning including the new class name :-)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I've included your insights in my answer.