# How to get Java to recognize the Postgres driver?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc

I'm trying to get some Java code to connect to Postgres. Just an attempt to get it to connect to a database at all, in the first instance:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
  private static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dvdrental";
  private static final String user = "postgres";
  private static final String password = "...";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    var conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
  }
}
```

This gets a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dvdrental
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
```

Seems straightforward enough, I need to add a suitable driver as a dependency, so I added the following to `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

... and it makes no difference at all; `mvn package` followed by running the program, still gets the same runtime error.

Is there something else I need to do, to tell Java to actually go ahead and use that driver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039265/what-exactly-does-this-do-class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-newinstance

There you go sir.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: @SuchandraT That looks along the right lines! but I get `ClassNotFoundException` using both "org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver" and "org.postgresql.Driver"; is there another name the Postgres driver is known by?

Comment: @g00se `java -jar target/olivine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: You need to make sure that olivine jar has postgres driver jar.

Comment: I suspected so. If you're going to do that it should be `java -cp whatever-postgres-driver.jar;target/olivine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar a.b.c.YourClass` (assuming Windows and the fact you're *not* using Maven Shade)

Comment: No problem. If you want to use `-jar` you should use Maven Shade